# There is a lot of 'plist' in sandbox, more than 1 Gb of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a problem with `NSUserdefault`. There are a lot of `plist` in the sandbox, more than 1 Gb memory looks like temporary files.

I use `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"isSafeAvailable"];
```

or

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"VPLaunchAdRemovedInfoKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

1. Is this a bug of iOS?
2. How to fix it?

[image: Please check the image here]

Comment: You need to show us the code in which you use it.

Comment: OK, I have added the code, It is common and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Plist files are Apple system files that store your preferences for a particular program. If you delete a plist file, the next time you start up Neat, it creates a new, default plist file.

In certain situations, you will need to delete the plist files to fix an issue

See steps and more details for this. https://neat.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/2731059-deleting-plist-files

Comment: OP did not even mention Neat. And he is not talking about general plist file. it is related to his application that he's building (hence the censored bundle id).

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you are sure that the plist belongs to your app, you can delete them all.